# How can I queue failing or missed backup jobs, even if the computer is asleep or off?

Tags: scripts, ssh, backup, rsync

I'm thinking about using `rsync` to backup my laptop to my home server via `ssh`. I want to do it daily so I plan to use `crontab`. My question is: if a job is missed (say the backup is scheduled for a time when the laptop is turned off) will it be executed as soon as possible? or it will simply be missed?

Comment: It will be missed, *unless* you run a script that keeps the job in queue if it fails.

Comment: I'm pretty positive the script you are hinting to is waaaay over my skills... would it be too much to ask how this can be achieved?

Comment: The cron job, is it run on your laptop or you server? Also, what is your rsync command exactly?

Comment: I'm currently running (from my laptop) a simple

rsync -av –delete -e ssh /folder/ user@server:/folder/

Comment: What about suspend, does it also need to check after suspend if there are surpassed backups?

Comment: I would simply ensure myself that a backup of my laptop is run every three days or ASAP after the 3 days deadline (To be honest I rarely turn off my laptop, it's almost always suspended, but I store quite important work and I must ensure a backup plan for myself)

Comment: Would You find another solution acceptable? Running a queued backup on *client* side is complicated to do, strictly from cron, since it would have to read the crontab and look if the last backup ran. From a script, this would be *a lot* easyer. At the same time, it would add zero to the load if it is written well.

Comment: Sure, I'm open minded to any solution as long as my data is safe: I was trying to use cron and rsync because I thought that was the best option but I'm surely no expert on this topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specifically asked for it:

***Queue failing or missed backup jobs, even if the computer is asleep or off***

When running backup jobs *on the server*, it would be relatively easy to retry (queue) failed jobs, since we may assume the server will be the "stable" factor. Queue -ing missed backups can be done by routing the cronjob to a script, creating a queue whenever the backup fails.

When the jobs run *on the client* however, the story is slightly different. When we run the job from `cron`, how do we notice a job failed? Since the job was not initiated if the client computer is sleeping or switched off, things would get far more complicated to set up from cron.

Therefore, if you want to run scheduled backups, making sure failed or missed jobs will run on the first occasion, I would suggest not using cron *at all*.

#### Setup scheduled/queued backups in a single file

The solution below is a relatively simple to set up, by the following steps:

1. Write, and test, an `rsync` backup command. Use `grsync`if you are unsure about how to do that.
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, give it the name (e.g.) of the backup job, like:

   ```
   backup1.py
   ```
3. In the head of the script, make appropriate settings:

   ```py
   #--- enter the working rsync command below
   rsync = "rsync -r -t --progress -s '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test2' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test1'"
   #--- set backup time interval below in hours/minutes
   interval = [0, 10]
   #--- set message True if you'd like a warning if a job failed (else False)
   message = True
   ```

   Enter the `rsync` command *between double quotes*, like in the example.

   - Save the script with a `unique_name.py`

That's it. From the start time of the script, the backups will run exactly after each interval. If the job fails, it is queued (retried once per minute) until it can be run succesfully. After that, the new backup is set on the exact scheduled (next) time.

- Subsequently, test- run the script with the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/script.py
  ```

  If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/script.py
  ```

*The script*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import os
import datetime

#--- enter the working rsync command below
rsync = "rsync -r -t -s '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test2' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test1'"
#--- set backup time interval below in hours/minutes
interval = [24, 0]
#--- set message True if you'd like a warning if a job failed (else False)
message = True
#--- set the max- size of the logfile below (n- lines)
maxlog = 100

#--- don't change anything below
backup_id = os.path.basename(__file__).split(".")[0]
home = os.environ["HOME"]
datefile = home+"/next_backup_"+backup_id; logfile = home+"/backup_log_"+backup_id
print(datefile, logfile)
interval = (interval[0]*3600)+(interval[1]*60)
failed = False

def failed_message():
    # shows a zenity message if a backup failed
    subprocess.Popen([
        "zenity",
        "--info",
        "--text="+backup_id+" failed\n"+\
        "See "+logfile]) 

def readable_t(sec):
    # converts epoch time to readable date & time
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sec).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def currtime():
    # returns current (epoch) time
    return int(time.strftime("%s"))

def sync(failed):
    # performs the rsync command, on errors: writes to log and shows message
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(["/bin/bash", "-c", rsync])
        set_next(planned, interval, currt)
        return False
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        if failed == False:
            open(logfile, "+a").write(readable_t(planned)+" failed\n")
            if message == True:
                failed_message()
        return True

def next_run():
    # reads current queue file, creates it if it doesn't exist
    try:
        return int(open(datefile).read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        currt = currtime()
        open(datefile, "wt").write(str(currt))
        return currt

def set_next(lastr, interval, currt):
    # creates the next queue, maintains the log file
    nextrun = lastr
    while nextrun <= currt:
        nextrun += interval
    open(datefile, "wt").write(str(nextrun))
    newline = [readable_t(lastr)+" succesfully finished on "+\
                        readable_t(currtime())+"\n"]
    try:
        limited_lines = open(logfile).readlines()[-maxlog+1:]+newline
    except FileNotFoundError:
        limited_lines = newline
    with open(logfile, "wt") as log:
        for l in limited_lines:
            print("4")
            log.write(l)

while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    planned = next_run(); currt = currtime()
    if currt > planned:
        failed = sync(failed)
```

#### Furthermore

- The script keeps a logfile, named after the backupscript.
  The maximum number of lines, to keep in the logfile, can be set in the head of the script:

  ```py
  #--- set the max- size of the logfile below (n- lines)
  maxlog = 50
  ```

  *An example*

  [image]

  In the example below, the script is set to backup every five minutes, starting from 11:10 a.m.

  - The first two (11:10, 11:15) run succesfully
  - The third one (planned 11:20) fails, due to the fact that the laptop sleeps. The job is queued and executed slightly delayed. The job finishes at 11:27, the next scheduled backup runs on 10:30
  - Then, the job, scheduled at 11:35 fails, due to the fact that the server is not available. If you set `message = True`:

    [image]
  - The job is queued and successfully runs later, at 11:41:44

  *and so on*

#### How to reset the start time of the backup?

Simply delete the queue file in your home directory of the corresponding backup job (starting with `next_backup_`) the current time will the be the new start time of the cycle.

#### How it works under the hood

- When the script starts up, the first backup is created (starting within a minute from startup of the script).
- When the job is finished, the script creates a queue file, timed at the (start) time of the *finished job* + the set *backup interval*.
- Once per minute, the script checks if the queue file is "over time", comparing the current time to the queued time. If so, the script runs the backup job, creates the new queue and so on. 
  *What happens if the laptop (client) is switched off?* 
  Then the latest created queue file is not refreshed (overwritten) by the script, so it will run the delayed backup on the first occasion after starting up (or waking up) of the computer.
  *How is the next backup queue created after that?*
  The next backup is always calculated in whole steps of the backup interval, and will always be "in phase". In other words; if the first backup was made on 12:00 p.m., and you set the interval to `[24, 0]`, the next backup will always be queued at `12:00` of the next day.

#### Multiple backup jobs?

The script sleeps most of the time. If not, it only looks into the queue file once per minute. SInce means *nothing* to your system, it is very well possible to run multiple backup jobs, each with their own log & queue file, at the same time. Since both the log- and queue file are named after the script's name, all you have to to is to give each of the scripts a unique name

Comment: Astounding job! I'm deeply grateful to you for the time and skills you offered!

Comment: Hi @Seb Thanks :) The script should be copied on the client, and run *on* the client. That is probably causing your issue. Possibly you run the before- last version btw (updated 2 days ago).

Comment: @Seb Sorry, sorry, accidentally left my own directories in the script... fixed now.

Comment: @Seb (on the comment on the answer below) Thanks for the nice question, as mentioned, using it myself now :)